# Set Default ACL rwx to a directory, can't create a sub-directory as the user

Tags: permissions, acl

As `root`, I created `/test` and set the default ACL with

```
setfacl -m -d dog:rwx /test
```

I verified the output of getfacl

```
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:dog:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Now, as the user `dog`, if I tried to create a directory in `/test`, I get

```
mkdir: can't create directory 'sub': Permission denied
```

Why is this so? If I setfacl without the default, getfacl shows `user:dog:rwx` instead of `default:user:dog:rwx` and `dog` could create a sub-directory there.

Note: It was tested inside of a VM, and the text on the VM screen is not copiable, so I add screen capture instead.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `setfacl -m -d ...` and `setfacl -m ...` have different behaviors when the ACL is assigned. The **Default ACLs** are used to be inherited. So you have to assign **ACLs** when you want to give *acl permission* to a user and assign **Default ACLs** to inherit perms under some dir.

### Explanation

---

First, I will the dir (as root) `/test` and check its permissions:

```bash
$> mkdir /test ; ls -ld /test 
#Output
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec  1 17:52 test
```

As you can see the group and other have no **write** permissions by default. Let's take a look the difference between both `setfacl` commands.

##### Using `setfacl -m guest:rwx /test`

When I run that command (as root) I can see the following outputs by using the following commands:

```bash
ls -ld /test
#Output
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Dec  1 17:57 test
```

As you can see above the directory has now **write** permissions for the group. By the way, if you remove **ACLs** by using: `setfacl --remove-all /test` and you use `ls -ld /test` you will notice that `/test` permissions are reverted to previous ones (`drwxr-xr-x`).

```bash
getfacl -e /test
#Output
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:guest:rwx                  #effective:rwx
group::r-x                      #effective:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

I used `getfacl -e` to print all effective rights whose are important to know how the **ACLs** works.

Now I will try to create a file under `/test` directory with `guest` and `edgar` users:

```bash
(user:guest)> touch /test/fuzz
#All is ok!
```

```bash
(user:edgar)> touch /test/buzz
#touch: cannot touch '/test/buzz': Permission denied
```

You can notice that `guest` user was able to create `/test/fuzz` file while `edgar` was not. That behavior is correct because of the **ACL** assigned to `guest`.

---

##### Using `setfacl -dm guest:rwx /test`

In my case the syntax `setfacl -m -d guest:rwx /test` is not valid (I'm using openSUSE Tumbleweed). You can also use `setfacl -m d:guest:rwx /test`.

Now running the command with **Default ACLs** I have the following:

```bash
ls -ld /test
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 root root 4096 Dec  1 18:39 test
```

```bash
getfacl -e /test
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:guest:rwx          #effective:rwx
default:group::r-x              #effective:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

As you can see now, the `/test` directory has no **write** permissions for the group. And by using `getfacl ...` I get that the *default guest user* has `rwx` permissions but as I said before they will be used to be inherited. So if you want that in your case `dog` user can write to `/test` dir is using: `setfacl -m dog:rwx /test`.

---

##### About Default ACLs or inherited ACLs

1. I will set the following **ACL** and **Default ACL**:

```bash
#ACL
setfacl -m guest:rwx /test

#Default ACL
sudo setfacl -dm guest:r /test
```

2. Now I will create a directory under `/test` as `guest` user:

```bash
(user:guest) /test: mkdir only_r
(user:guest) /test: ls -ld only_r
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 guest guest 4096 Dec  1 19:19 only_r/
(user:guest): getfacl -e only_r
# file: only_r/
# owner: guest
# group: guest
user::rwx
user:edgar:r--                  #effective:r--
user:guest:r--                  #effective:r--
group::r-x                      #effective:r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:edgar:r--          #effective:r--
default:user:guest:r--          #effective:r--
default:group::r-x              #effective:r-x
default:mask::r-x
default:other::r-x
```

3. Now I will try to change to `only_r` dir and create a file

```bash
(user:guest) /test: cd only_r
(user:guest) /test/only_r: touch fuzz
(user:guest) /test/only_r: ls
fuzz
```

As you can above I was able to change to only_r and create a file although ACLs have not **execution** and **write** permissions (if a directory does not have execution perms then I cannot `cd` to it). However this behavior is correct because the Unix permissions and the owner `drwxr-xr-x+ 2 guest guest` allow to  the `guest` user to `cd` and `create` files to `/test/only_r`

4. Finally with `edgar` user I will try to `cd` to `/test/only_r` and create some file:

```bash
(user:edgar) : cd /test/only_r
cd: permission denied: /test/only_r
(user:edgar) : echo jaja > only_r/fuzzbuzz
permission denied: only_r/fuzzbuzz
```