# setfacl -m doesn't add permission to that of the traditional file permissions?

Tags: acl

There is a directory `/test/test2/`. Its owner is `root` and the group is `test` and the permission is `drwxr-xr-x`. I executed `setfacl -m group:test:w ./` in that directory.

Now, as the user `test` whose groups includes `test`, if I run `getfacl ./` in that directory, the output is,

```
# file: .
# owner: root
# group: test
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:test:-w-
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Now, if I execute `touch test.txt`, I get `touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied`. Why is this so? Doesn't the `setfacl -m` add the permission to the `chmod` permission? I mean, I gave the `test` group write permission with `setfacl`, and since the group had `r-x` in traditional permission (that can be changed with `chmod`), doesn't this effectively give `rwx` to the `test` group?

I have tried `namei -l /test/test2/`, and the output was

```
f: /test/test2/
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root test
drwxrwxr-x root test test2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
group:test:-w-
```

The group `test` does really have write permissions but not execute permissions so you will not be able to create anything under that directory.
You will have to assign permission with something like this:

```bash
setfacl -m group:test:wx ./
```

*Even if you assign `UNIX` **write** permissions but not **execution** permissions you won't be able to create anything*

Comment: You can find something related [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149184/414186)

Comment: But the group already had r-x permission on the directory, and the directory's group was "test". So, when ACL is set, the traditional permissions are ignored for the same group?

Comment: @DamnVegetables As far as I know I would say `yes`. When a file/dir has `ACLs` this checks the permissions for the given user and if this one is not allowed for making *reading,writing,executing* then the action is rejected. Maybe you are confusing by what I answered to you some days ago in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727012/414186): *"However this behavior is correct because the Unix permissions and the owner drwxr-xr-x+ 2 guest guest allow to the guest user to cd and create files to /test/only_r"*

Comment: In that case the directory `only_r` was owed by the same user so it was able to change/modify/create files under that directory. In this case as you said the `test2` is owned by **root** as user, and **test** as group. But, I remember reading(but I did not find the thread) something about `user permissions` are *primordial* over `group permissions`.

Comment: For example, if I have a file with this perms: `--x rwx ---  test test`, as you can the test user has `x` permissions but its group `test` has `rwx` permissions. Thus if you try to edit the file or reading it you will get a `Permission Denied` even if you are in the same group.
In your case it seems that the `test` group is ignored and the ACLs are applied.  You can *swap* the owner of your `test2` dir:
`sudo chown test:root`. And since the dir is now owned by `test` as a user the `ACLs` will be ignored (if you assign only write perms you will be able to read/write/change to the dir).